# Deploy Node.js + Express to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Deploy Node.js + Express to server

I am brand new to Node.js and Express development, and before I get too deep in a new project that I’ve sold my boss on using this newer tech on, I just want to test the technology on my server to make sure it all works. We are using a dedicated server on Pair.com for hosting.

Background, we’ve done all previous dev work in PHP/mySQL, and that’s what our server is set up to run most efficiently, I guess.

That being said, I’ve been able to SSH into the server, check that Node is installed (it is, and running version 12.18.1), CD into my domain, and install express.

I’ve got the following file I’m running using npm start, which runs this app.js file.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hey this is your website.');
});

app.get('/joke', function (req, res) {
  var joke =
    'What do you call a dog that does magic tricks? A labracadabrador.';
  res.send(joke);
});

app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('Server running on 8080!');
});
```

When I run this, I get “Server is running on 8080!” in my SSH terminal. However, if I visit that main domain or /joke, I get “page not found”.

My theory is that Express is running on 8080, but my website is listening on port 80, and so while Express is technically running, my website isn’t paying any attention to that app.js file.

If I try to run Express on port 80, I get an EACCESS error.

My question is, how do I deploy and get my server to listen to the app.js file that is seemingly running on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution is to use a reverse proxy to sit in front of your express server. The reverse proxy will listen on port 80 and forward requests to the express app listening on port 8080.

You could look into using `nginx` to accomplish this. There are lots of tutorials out there on configuring it to work with express apps.

Comment: This is kind of what I ended up doing, so I'm marking it as my accepted answer with a clarification: I'm running nginx with something called Phusion Passenger, which my hosting company has installed on our server to run Node apps. I needed to first enable that (a setting called mod_passenger in Pair) to be able to run nginx or my node app at all.

Comment: @AmyMurphy Glad you were able to figure it out. Never heard of Phusion Passenger, but that is interesting - will have to look more into that

Answer (score 0):

I once ran into a similar problem. I solved it by using CORS middleware. I installed CORS on my Node server, and used it as a middleware like

```
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000" }));
```

Notice how i used the Client URL for origin. You can replace the URL with your client URL. I hope this helps